# HTML Number Field Increases/Decreases With Mouse Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've noticed that HTML number fields change value when the mouse scrolls within the field. I would like to disable this (ideally without JS). I've found this [Disable scrolling on `<input type=number>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712295/disable-scrolling-on-input-type-number) but again I would like to accomplish this without any JS. Is there an HTML tag or setting I can use to disable this functionality? Ideally I would like to keep the field as a `number` as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is native behaviour, and in many cases taking away native behaviour is bad...

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7571867/1045794

Comment: Again, I would like to accomplish this without any JS/Jquery.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to do this without javascript would be to make it a text field and not a number field.

Comment: You cannot do that without JS, so I closed as a dupe.