# is there why to remove increase/decrease number in input type="number"?

Tags: javascript, html

In `<input type="number">` you can by default increase/decrease number from click arrow up and arrow down
is there a way to remove this behavior?

Note: I don't talk about the arrow in the input I talk about click arrow up and arrow down in the keyboard

Comment: Use text input. that's the solution.

Comment: In your initial sentence you talk about _clicking_ the up an down arrows in the input, but then in your note you're talking about disabling the arrow keys (from the keyboard), are you talking about disabling arrow keys on the keyboard or disabling the up/down buttons within the input field itself?

Comment: It talks about the scrolling but you may update it accordingly for keyboard events.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712295/disable-scrolling-on-input-type-number

Comment: when you have input type="number" if you click up arrow or down arrow the number increase or decrease I want to disabled that, and  want to use input number not text.