# Yup Cast Number to String

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm using Formik and Yup and I'm trying to create a Yup validation and I can't seem to find any help anywhere.

I have an input as a text:

```
<label htmlFor="loan_amount" className={styles.form_label}>
                    Loan Amount:
                    <br />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Amount"
                      className={styles.loan_input}
                      {...formik.getFieldProps("loan_amount")}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.loan_amount && formik.errors.loan_amount ? (
                      <div className={styles.error_msg}>
                        {formik.errors.loan_amount}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </label>
```

And I'm trying to validate the text as a number so I can make use of the min() and max() attributes of Yup.number() validation.

This is my validation schema:

```
loan_amount: Yup.number().max((40 / 29) * parseFloat((income?.value)?.replace(/,/g, '')), `Your Maximum loan amount is ${Math.round((40 / 29) * parseFloat((income?.value)?.replace(/,/g, ''))).toLocaleString()}`).required("Loan amount is required")
```

The problem I have right now is that being a text field, I want to ensure that it's only numbers that are inputted. So users won't be able to input comma, dot, or any form of text.

I know that using a number input will give me exactly what I want, but I also noticed that I have this issue with a number input:

The value changes when the user scrolls. I implemented this fix but it didn't work:

```
<label htmlFor="loan_amount" className={styles.form_label}>
                    Loan Amount:
                    <br />
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      onFocus={this?.blur()}
                      onWheel={this?.blur()}
                      placeholder="Amount"
                      className={styles.loan_input}
                      {...formik.getFieldProps("loan_amount")}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.loan_amount && formik.errors.loan_amount ? (
                      <div className={styles.error_msg}>
                        {formik.errors.loan_amount}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </label>
```

I want to retain the input as a text but I need a way to specifically prevent users from typing comma or dot or any letter at all.

By the way, I've also tried using a pattern on the text input but it's not working either.

I tried this:

```
<label htmlFor="monthly_salary" className={styles.form_label}>
                    Monthly Salary:
                    <br />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      pattern="[0-9]+"
                      placeholder="Input Salary"
                      id="gross_monthly_income"
                      className={styles.loan_input}
                      {...formik.getFieldProps("gross_monthly_income")}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.gross_monthly_income &&
                      formik.errors.gross_monthly_income ? (
                      <div className={styles.error_msg}>
                        {formik.errors.gross_monthly_income}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </label>
```

Any relevant help would be much appreciated so I can sort this out. I don't seem to be able to find any answers despite all the research I have done.

I also don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: your validation schema is missing some brackets or has extra bracket, can you edit? Also, you dont want the user to scroll the number field?

Comment: I have edited my validation schema. I missed out a few things when I was copying and pasting, but they've been included now.

No, I don't want the user to scroll the number field - I have already removed the scroll arrows using CSS.

Comment: [check this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-mui-v5-forked-qzf0rk?file=/src/App.js) you can use `type="number"` and use `onkeypress` events to prevent alphabets etc

Comment: Thank you for your input. The number field still scrolls on mousewheel.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076231/13405106)  may helps