# Javascript disable scroll on input type=text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Having a table with input fields as td. Example of input field:

```
`<input type="text" value="20.300,00" style="max-width: 95px;">`
```

Im trying to disable the ability to scroll in this element. This is my code:

```
`$(document).on("wheel", function(event) {
          if ($(document.activeElement).is("input[type='text']")) {
              $(document.activeElement).blur();
          }
      });`
```

With this code, it's still possible to scroll once, which changes the value once and afterwards its removing focus from the input field.

How can i completely remove the ability to scroll?

I've tried to use:

```
`event.preventDefault();`
```

That doesn't seem to be a option.

Comment: If I can't "scroll" in the field, then I will probably not be able to properly edit the value either. So _why_ are those input fields to begin with then, if you apparently are trying to make proper editing impossible?

Comment: It should still be possible to change the value using your keyboard. I just want to prevent changeing the value using the scrollwheel.

Comment: *"With this code, it's still possible to scroll once, which changes the value once..."* Are you sure the `input` you've shown at the top of the question is really what you're using? Because you have `type="text"` on it, so [scrolling doesn't do anything to the value](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ra0yg5pj/). If you had `type="number"`, scrolling changes the value in Firefox (not Chromium browsers), but not `type="text"`.

Comment: Yes, it is the right Input. The input field is type=text, but is formatted to only contain numbers between 0-9.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reset the scroll to zero, which effectively disables scrolling.

```
$('input[type=text]').on("scroll", function(){
    $(this).scrollLeft(0);
});
```

And if you wanted to re-enable scrolling on some event or interaction.

```
$(this).unbind("scroll");
```

Answer (score -1):

Good afternoon,

You could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712295/disable-scrolling-on-input-type-number), There is no builtin feature to prevent this as far as I know.

Anyway the post I linked shows you how to 'disable' mousewheel scrolling while the input element is active.

Hope it helps!

**Note:** you would obviously change `input[type=number]` to `input[type=text]`

Comment: The answer in the question you provided, does not work. Im still able to scroll once.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you will add **event.preventDefault()** inside your if condition then I think it will do the job.

Comment: It doesn't work adding "event.preventDefault()", i do still have the ability to scroll.

Comment: The question literally says *"I've tried to use: `event.preventDefault();`"* at the end.