# How do I completely disallow an integer's value to be modified using the mouse wheel?

Tags: opus-ui

I have json dashboard with an input with dataType "integer" property. When i click the input, the mouse wheel can change it's value. How do I disable the mouse wheel's ability to increase/decrease the value of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that implements the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712295/disable-scrolling-on-input-type-number) in Opus.

Unfortunately, we need to blur the element to get around the browser default. In this solution we solve that by focusing the element again ASAP:

```
{
    "type": "input",
    "prps": {
        "dataType": "integer",
        "scps": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "evalUnsafeJs",
                        "value": [
                            "const el = document.querySelector(`[id='((variable.triggeredFrom))'] input`);",
                            "el.addEventListener('wheel', async e => {",
                            "    el.blur();",
                            "    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r));",
                            "    el.focus();",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "inlineKeys": [
                            "value"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```